# sir( ) igraph, beta (or gamma) between 0 and 1 => Error

Tags: r, simulation, igraph

I am simulating a non-dimensional SIR model using igraph.

I run into Internal Errors when beta or gamma is a fraction between 0 and 1. Is this not allowed in iGraph?

For example:

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000)
sir(g,0.4,1)

# Error in .Call("R_igraph_sir", graph, beta, gamma, no.sim, PACKAGE = "igraph") : 
#  At sir.c:185 : Internal SIR error, Internal error, likely a bug in igraph
```

For my model I'll need to use following parameters:

```
b  <- 0.0006393279 # beta
gm <- 1/7          # gamma
```

Is there a way to use above parameters with `sir()` ?

Comment: If it says that it is a bug, then why not report a bug at https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues ?

Comment: Hi @GaborCsardi , I was wondering if anyone in your group was able to take a look into the sir ( )?  I coded similar functions in R but none of them are remotely as fast at the igraph sir ( ), when it works.

Comment: @Hitaysh please i have the same issue, did you resolve it??

Comment: @Sasa88 I couldn't get iGraph to work. I coded up a simulation in R which didn't use the iGraph library.  It was a lot slower but did the trick.  [Epimodel](http://www.epimodel.org/) could be a helpful alternative, so I'd recommend exploring it.

Comment: @Hitaysh Epimodel is not good for me, i want to try the SIM model in igraph graph because it is represented as the real graph (i read the graph using igraph, my graph is not random). please can you put your code here.

Comment: @Sasa88 I'm embarassed to say that I seemed to have lost it.  It took code from [here]{http://chengjunwang.com/en/2014/03/simulate-network-diffusion-with-R/} as a starting point and updated accordingly.  Hope this helps.